# Xamarin.Forms PageControl for all Platforms

Tags: windows-phone-8, xamarin, carousel, xamarin.forms, pagecontrol

Is there a possibility to implement some kind of paging control (like in iOS) for all three platforms with Xamarin.Forms incl. other controls on the same page? I spent several hours asking google but without any success. My task is to build a Page which embeds some kind of CarouselPage and Contentpage within the same Page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not out of the box, but there're some custom implementations:

https://github.com/chrisriesgo/xamarin-forms-carouselview
or
https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/CarouselView

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Have you experience with these controls - CarouselView? I will give it a try.

Comment: Yes, used the first one and works well, the second one had a problems with swipe gestures on iOS.